Ubuntu 20.04 Wired Ethernet Connection Failed on 1st ever use
I have had my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for some time now, and earlier releases before that.
Recently I tried to connect to a TP-Link switch via the Ethernet socket, which I've never used before.
I enabled Settings > Network > Wired 100Mb/s and got - Connection Failed Activation of network connection failed.
When I unpluged the cable I got - Cable unplugged, so something registered.
When I look at the Settings for the Wired connection I see:

IP Address fe80::142d:bba7:465d:e9a1
Hardware Address 80:FA:5B:79:FB:DB

I presume these are from the TP-Link Switch
When I look at Network Connections it shows TP-Link under Ethernet never used, so again something registered.
I installed Net-Tools as prompted by $ ifconfig -a
That finds 3 devices:

Loopback Interface (lo)
Unknown Interface (enp59s0f1) - which I think is the one TP-Link is
plugged into as it shows the same IPv6 address
Unknown Interface (wlp64s0)

What do I need to do to get this connection to work?

Maybe your ethernet network does not have DHCP. If you run "ip l sh enp59s0f1" and it says "state UP", then the physical connection is fine. You just need an IP.

I connected laptop directly to router via ethernet to test the port and it worked fine.
Turns out I need a different cable (crossover?) to connect to TP-Link switch dashboard.
